# footer background not displaying full height

Tags: html, css

Was cleaning up some html in the footer of a new site and now the footer background color is not displaying for the full height. It was displaying correctly before the clean up and I have not touched anything in the CSS, wondering if I am just overlooking something small.

Current CSS:

```
#footer {
width: 100%;
margin: 20px 0;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 0;
background-color: rgba(0, 151, 214, 1);
}
```

Note: I didn't want to specify a height ie. 600px and then have to readjust a height or min-height for several breakpoints.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The footer element (id=footer) is "collapsing" because all of its children are floated. To work around this problem you could apply the clearfix hack. Either you could add a new class called `.clearfix` and add that class to the footer element, or you could apply this code to the footer element;

```
#footer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You can read more about the clearfix / group hack here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Thank you. That resolved the issue. Just read up on that link as well.